# Setting up a Ruby On Rails project on windows with nokogiri problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed Ruby `2.5.1`, I have the IDE **RubyMine**.

I started a new project and my `gemfile` looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.0'
```

When I run the bundle I get this error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 12.3.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 1.0.0
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.1.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.7.1
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Fetching nokogiri 1.8.2
Installing nokogiri 1.8.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/ext/nokogiri
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180408-7088-1nltbvj.rb extconf.rb
--use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
pkg-config could not be used to find libxml-2.0
Please install either `pkg-config` or the pkg-config gem per

    gem install pkg-config -v "~> 1.1"

pkg-config could not be used to find libxslt
Please install either `pkg-config` or the pkg-config gem per

    gem install pkg-config -v "~> 1.1"

pkg-config could not be used to find libexslt
Please install either `pkg-config` or the pkg-config gem per

    gem install pkg-config -v "~> 1.1"

ERROR: cannot discover where libxml2 is located on your system. please make sure
`pkg-config` is installed.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-exslt-dir
    --without-exslt-dir
    --with-exslt-include
    --without-exslt-include=${exslt-dir}/include
    --with-exslt-lib
    --without-exslt-lib=${exslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libexslt-config
    --without-libexslt-config

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.8.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.8.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
            nokogiri
```

I tried following the [instructions here](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html), and do `gem install nokogiri` and it said that `1 gem was installed`.

But then I ran bundle update again, and I got that error again.

I did `nokogiri -version`:

```
C:\Users\Ben\RubymineProjects\untitled1>nokogiri -version
# Nokogiri (1.8.2)
    ---
    warnings: []
    nokogiri: 1.8.2
    ruby:
      version: 2.5.1
      platform: x64-mingw32
      description: ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]
      engine: ruby
    libxml:
      binding: extension
      source: packaged
      libxml2_path: "/home/flavorjones/code/oss/nokogiri/ports/x86_64-w64-mingw32/libxml2/2.9.7"
      libxslt_path: "/home/flavorjones/code/oss/nokogiri/ports/x86_64-w64-mingw32/libxslt/1.1.32"
      libxml2_patches: []
      libxslt_patches: []
      compiled: 2.9.7
      loaded: 2.9.7
```

**fyi, it works perfectly on Ubuntu, on the same ruby version and rubymine.** *But I can not be bothered to double boot or use a VM everytime* So I need this solved somehow.

If anyone had this issue?

Comment: Installing Nokogiri can often be a pain, due to the `libxml` dependencies etc... There are *hundreds* of SO questions about this. For example, see the comments in [this](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/5207) github thread. My honest advice, however, would be to not use Windows!! Linux/Mac systems make life much easier.

Comment: By the way, rubymine is irrelevant to this question. That's just your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue around 7-8 months back along with the issues of some other gems. Couldn't figure out the issue then. So eventually had to switch to Linux, so i would you to switch too because if you are going to work on Rails for some time then problems with gems will just keep hitting you.